# Edit button which i clicked in QTreewidgetItem in QtreeWidget which have dynamic data

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a lot of buttons in QTreeWidget, how can I reference to button that I clicked or get her object.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, main_window_ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
       self.setupUi(self)
       self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()

       self.treeWidget.setColumnCount( len(HEADERS) )
       self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels( HEADERS )
       self.treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(True)
    
       for i in range(10):
           item = QTreeWidgetItem()
           self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)
           item.setText(0, str(i))
           item.setText(2, "123456789")
           item.setText(3, "Ready")
           item.setText(4, "2021-04-12")

           checkbox = QCheckBox()
           checkbox.setStyleSheet(checkboxst)
           self.treeWidget.setItemWidget(item, 1, checkbox)

           button = QPushButton()
           button.setText("Start")
           button.setStyleSheet(buttonst)
           self.treeWidget.setItemWidget(item, 5, button)
           # button.clicked.connect(self.getValue)

           it = QTreeWidgetItem()
           it.setText(0, "Edited")
           item.addChild(it)

       self.treeWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.getValue)

       #snip...


   def getValue(self):
       index = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
```

I need to change text in button only that i clicked, how can i refer only to button that i clicked?

Comment: What text do you want to change?

Comment: In button from "Start" to "Stop" , but i don't know how reference to this button which generated . @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to determine which button was pressed then you can use the sender method:

```py
button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)
```

```
def handle_clicked(self):
    button = self.sender()
    if isinstance(button, QPushButton):
        button.setText("Stop" if button.text() == "Start" else "Start")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot, I admire you.